# How to check if the URL consists of only one route parameter?

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to generate a function which gives this response:

`www.soundcloud.com/abc` -> **true**

`www.soundcloud.com/abc/1` -> **false**

`http://www.soundcloud.com/abc` -> **true**

`https://www.soundcloud.com/abc` -> **true**

`https://www.soundcloud.com/abc/1` -> **false**

Please help! I am not good in regex related things.

Comment: Please post what you have tried and where you got stuck, StackOverflow is for helping you with your code, not making it all for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var myString = 'http://www.soundcloud.com/abc';
console.log(/^http\:\/\/www.soundcloud.com\/[^\/]+\/?$/.test(myString));
```

The beginning is straightforward: `^` at the beginning of the regex denotes that the string should match this pattern from its beginning, followed by the top-level URL you are trying to match.

Then, `[^\/]+` will match one or more characters that are *not* the forward slash (`^` negates, `\/` escapes the forward slash character).

And since sometimes URLs end in a slash, we have tested for an optional ending forward slash with `\/?`, followed by `$`, meaning that the string should end there. So this would test true for both `abc/` and `abc`.

RegEx is not that difficult to grasp and can make life infinitely easier in so many situations. MDN has a really good and simple reference page on it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions